# QGraphicsProxyWidget animations not working

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qt4.7

I'm trying to perform some animations using a QGraphicsProxyWidget but am not seeing any being applied. For example if I want to just rotate a QGraphicsTextItem this code works:

```
      QGraphicsView *view_ = new QGraphicsView(this);          
      QGraphicsScene *scene_ = new QGraphicsScene(view);
QGraphicsTextItem *text_item_ = new QGraphicsTextItem("This is some sample text to\ntest if we can rotate the\nimage correctly");
      scene_->addItem(text_item_);
      text_item_->rotate(180);
      view->setScene(scene_);
```

However this doesn't actually seem to do anything:

```
      QLabel* label =  new QLabel(this);
      label->setText("This is some sample text to\ntest if we can rotate the\nimage correctly");
      QGraphicsView *view_ = new QGraphicsView(this);          
      QGraphicsScene *scene_ = new QGraphicsScene(view);
QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy_widget_ = new QGraphicsProxyWidget();
      proxy_widget_->setWidget(label);
      scene_->addItem(proxy_widget__);
      proxy_widget_->rotate(180);
      view->setScene(scene_);
```

Nor does doing it like this:

```
QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy_widget_ = scene_->addWidget(label).
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Merlin. Figured out the issue. If you remove the parenting from the QLabel it works.

So change this:

```
QLabel* label =  new QLabel(this);
```

To this:

```
QLabel* label =  new QLabel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code adds the proxy widget and calls: -

```
proxy_widget->rotate(180);
```

If you look at the [QGraphicsProxyWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsproxywidget.html) documentation, you'll see that it inherits from QGraphicsItem and that you should call the function [setRotation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#setRotation)

```
proxy_widget->setRotation(180);
```